# Unload event is not get called in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

Unload event is not get called only onload is get called. Other events are not get called.

```
else if (dl.DisplayID == 2)
{
   <div class="player__embed">
     <div style='background-color: #F5F5F5; height: 40px; position: absolute; margin-right: 8px; bottom: 
            -8px; right: -8px; width: 90px;z-index: 2147483647;'> </div>
       <iframe id="LessonDocument" src="https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=https://@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LoginURL"].ToString()/uploadedfiles/
@dl.DocFileName" style="width:100%; height:100%;" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
   </div>
}
```

what is the reason behind that?

Comment: It's because the content of the iframe is coming from a third party URL. Due to security features on the browser you cannot access the content (or events) from a cross-domain iframe.

Comment: In this case how can I get the time they viewed document and time they spent in reading document.